# Grep for string if exist after pattern

Tags: linux, grep

This command will find any file that has string 'PARTICULAR=' in it

```
 grep -r --include=\*.log 'PARTICULAR*=' *
```

Here are the results I get:

```
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=gfgfgfgkl5dfgfgf
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=56945674454rgfgfg
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=kjdghfidfgh4545454
```

Note the blanks after PARTICULAR=

How can I edit the command to only output if there is a text right after PARTICULAR=

I have tried

```
grep -r --include=\*.log 'PARTICULAR*=' * | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

But I got the same results (however the command ran much faster??)

Comment: Any such command will always be dramatically faster the second time due to disk caching.

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for the info, i will research about disk caching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 grep -rE --include=\*.log -o "PARTICULAR*=\w+"
```

Based on the output you included, you should now get:

```
$> grep -rE --include=\*.log -o "PARTICULAR*=\w+"
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=gfgfgfgkl5dfgfgf
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=56945674454rgfgfg
foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=gkjdghfidfgh4545454
```

Comment: This worked just like you mentioned. How can I get output of foo/bar.log:PARTICULAR=gfgfgfgkl5dfgfgf

Comment: Ah. I just updated [Brendan Gregory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51676552/8250648). If you follow the edit (adding the `-E` flag), that solution will do exactly what you want.

Comment: grep: conflicting matchers specified

Comment: The output produced result but it also pulled the text that is not right after =

Comment: if you're expecting alphabets after the "PARTICULAR=" then change the match condition to be `\w+` or `[A-z]+` instead of `.+`

Comment: Just realized some strings have "!" symbol. PARTICULAR=fdhfiu!djfdofj. Your command outputs "PARTICULAR=fdhfiu" (before !). How can I include ! ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following:

```
grep -r --include=\*.log 'PARTICULAR*=' * | awk -F'=' 'match($0,\/foo\/bar.log:PARTICULAR=[a-zA-Z]+/)'
```

OR

```
grep -Er --include=\*.log '\/foo\/bar.log:PARTICULAR*=[a-zA-Z]+' *
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gave me the same results I was getting

Comment: The 3rd option did not produce any results

Comment: Yep it worked but it also pulled strings before PARTICULAR

Comment: In some files i have "export PARTICULAR=xxxxxxxx" so some of the output is "export PARTICULAR=xxxxxxxx"

Comment: @ZM output : foo/bar.log:export PARTICULAR=gfgfgfgkl5dfgfgf

Comment: Yes it is, but i didnt want anything before "PARTICULAR" aka "export"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` to mean Any Character:

```
$ grep '^PARTICULAR=.' bar.log
PARTICULAR=gfgfgfgkl5dfgfgf
PARTICULAR=56945674454rgfgfg
PARTICULAR=kjdghfidfgh4545454
```

The `^` makes sure matches start at the beginning of the line (i.e. not `ANDINPARTICULAR=foo`) and the lack of `*` is to avoid matching `PARTICULA=foo` and `PARTICULARRRRRRR=foo` which your `R*` would allow.

Answer (score 1):

A modified regex should get you the results you want.

```
grep -rE --include=\*.log 'PARTICULAR*=.+' *
```

The `.` matches any character, and the `+` indicates that there is at least one character following the `=`.

Note: Since the `+` operator is part of extended regex, the `-E` flag needs to be added.

Comment: This looks promising but for some reason I did not get any results